# No topics published after costmap_2d building from git source

Tags: ros, navigation, roslaunch, costmap-2d, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was previously succesfully launching the default costmap_2d package that came with ROS hydro, Ubuntu 12.04, using the following launch file and yaml parameters file:

Parameters file:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link

rolling_window: false
width: 20.0
height: 20.0
resolution: 0.05

footprint: [[-0.325, -0.20], [-0.325, 0.20], [0.325, 0.20], [0.34, 0.0], [0.325, -0.20]]

plugins:

- {name: obstacles,   type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}

publish_frequency: 15.0
update_frequency: 15.0

obstacles:
track_unkown_space: false
observation_sources: optfl_replNaN_point_cloud
optfl_replNaN_point_cloud: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /projected_cloud_prev, sensor_frame: /base_link, clearing: true, marking: true, max_obstacle_height: 20, min_obstacle_height: 0, obstacle_range: 20, raytrace_range: 25, expected_update_rate: 0}

Now I want to modify the source code, I could not find it in /opt/ros any folder, so I cloned the navigation stack from git into a local folder, built it from source and running it using the same launch file and params file. However, there is no topic being published and the ROS_INFO message "  Subscribed to Topics:" is also not being shown on screen(my output type is "screen"). I have tried changing the namespace to "costmap_node/costmap" but no help.

Please help!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213573/no-topics-published-after-costmap_2d-building-from-git-source/) by [Ishani Chatterjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/23160/ishani-chatterjee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I found the answer, in the CMakeLists.txt of the costmap_2d package, in all the target_link_libraries of the executables, $catkin_LIBRARIES are not added in the git source code. I had to add ${catkin_LIBRARIES} in each target_link_libraries and it started working!!!

---

Originally posted by [Ishani Chatterjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/23160/ishani-chatterjee/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1